# How to eager load an association after eager loading on the parent?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I know how and what eager loading is, and I've searched around Google and StackOverflow for other eager loading questions. Some of them were enlightening, but none solved my particular question so I'm going to ask one myself.

Here is my schema:

```
class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :activities
  has_many :users_logged, source: :user, through: :activities
end

class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :organization
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :activities
end
```

This project was inherited and I can't do any major schema redesigns so if the question is not possible with the schema then so be it. I just want to try and speed up generation of these reports which involves loading all the Organizations, something like:

```
Organizations.includes(:users_logged).joins(:activities)
```

Now, I realize here that the `includes(:users_logged)` will load all the activities but the `joins(:activities)` is still necessary for the fields that are ordered/grouped by which I've excluded as they are not important to the question.

The question now is, I would like to eager load all the Activities for all users that have been selected by the `includes(:users_logged)` directive as I will not only need the Organization details, it's associated activities, and all users that have logged activities for the organization. In addition to that I need to load all the activities for the user (ideally associated with the organization but I can work that out once I figure out how to eager load).

My current implementation:

```
@orgs = Organization.includes(:users_logged).joins(:activities).all
@orgs.each do |org|
  org.users_logged.each do |user|
    # Just work with user.activities
  end
end
```

This results in a query per user that averages `0.3 ms` with the current amount of test data which adds up rather quickly. Is there a way to eager load all activities for a collection of users?

Comment: Have you tried `Organization.includes(:users_logged => :activities).joins(:activities).all` ?

Comment: I have not, but I will.

Comment: @Baldrick Nope, same results from the console. Still making individual requests.

Comment: @Baldrick Retract that, check my answer. You got me to thinking and I realized it was my own fault. But it seems I still need your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm posting this an answer to make sure that it's clear it's been resolved. Once I'm capable I will accept this as the correct answer.

Baldrick's comment got me to thinking about how exactly I was filtering out activities for the user so that I only had the activities logged to the active organization. I was performing:

```
user.activities.where("organization_id = ?", org.id)
```

Which would force a query every time regardless of what I've done. So I changed it to:

```
user.activities.select { |o| o.id == org.id }
```

Which now performs what I've wanted (after @Baldrick's recommendation as well).